# physics.addBody() with custom shapes in Corona SDK

Tags: collision-detection, corona-sdk

Does the physics.addBody() only work with Circles and Rectangles? Or is it possible to physics.addBody() on vector shapes or sprites or with masks or something?

Answer (score 2):

It works with more than just circles and rectangles. To be more specific,

> [physics.addBody()] Allows you to turn any Corona display object into a simulated physical object with one line of code, including the assignment of physical properties.

The full explanation, along with examples including a rectangle, circle, and polygon, can be found [here](http://developer.anscamobile.com/reference/index/physicsaddbody).

Answer (score 1):

If you want an irregular physics object, you have to specify the x and y coordinates of the physic body.  Complicated, but possible.

Or you can use a third-party tool like [PhysicsEdito](http://www.physicseditor.de)r.